# My Excel Add-in keeps disappearing after adding it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small task here in my company. The task is very simply, but yet very confusing. Many years back we had someone to create a small VBA code for Excel. The format at that time was Excel 97-2003 Today we are using Office 365. Now it is like this that the Add-ins icon disappears from Excel during startup, there are other icons which do not disappear and which is a "neighbour" to our icon. I can add it and the next time I start Excel it is there, but next time I start Excel it is not available. It is still selected in Excel Add-Ins, but it just doesn't appear. I have scoured Google for solutions, but the workarounds are not what I'm looking for. Some of the workarounds is to save the file in a trusted location, I did that, but it's the result. In matter of fact the file is now located in a trusted location. So I think it's the actual code that's causing the problem. The below code is original. I haven't done anything to it.

```
Option Base 1

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim cb As CommandBars
    Dim name As Variant
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    Set cb = Application.CommandBars

    For j = cb.Count To 1 Step -1
        If cb(j).name = "iSeries Access" Or cb(j).name = "Client Access" Then
            cb(j).Visible = False
            name = cb(j).name
            With cb(name)
                For i = .Controls.Count To 1 Step -1
                    If .Controls(i).Caption = "Format BPCS Bill Of Material..." Then
                        .Controls(i).Delete
                        GoTo nn
                    End If
                    If .Controls(i).Caption = "Custom" Then
                        .Controls(i).Enabled = True
                        .Controls(i).Visible = True
                    End If
                    If .Controls(i).Caption = "&Dialog" Then
                        .Controls(i).Enabled = True
                        .Controls(i).Visible = True
                    End If
    nn:
                Next
            End With
            cb(j).Visible = True
            j = 1
        End If
    Next

    With cb("Data").Controls.Item("Transfer &Data To iSeries...")
        .Enabled = True
        .Visible = True
    End With

    With cb("Data").Controls.Item("T&ransfer Data From iSeries...")
        .Enabled = True
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Set cb = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim ad As AddIns
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim CBar As CommandBars
    Dim Mbar As CommandBar
    Dim CMbar As CommandBarControl
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim warn As Dialog
    Dim j As Integer

    Set CBar = Application.CommandBars

    'On Error Resume Next

    Set ad = Application.AddIns


    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'found = False
    found = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'For i = ad.Count To 1 Step -1
    '    If ad(i).name = "cwbtfcai.dll" Then
    '        found = True
    '        If ad(i).Installed = False Then
    '            ad(i).Installed = True
    '        End If
    '        Exit For
    '    End If
    'Next

    'Set ad = Nothing

    If found = False Then
        warn = MsgBox("Couldn't find 'iSeries...' or 'Client Access Data Transfer' addin!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly)
        Application.AddIns("Simple_Excel_iSeries").Installed = False
        Workbooks("Simple_Excel_iSeries.xla").Close
     Else
        For i = CBar.Count To 1 Step -1
            If CBar(i).name = "IBM i Access" Or CBar(i).name = "iSeries  Access" Then
                Do
                    If CBar(i).Visible = True Then
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
                'CBar(i).Visible = False
                For j = 1 To CBar(i).Controls.Count
                    With CBar(i).Controls(j)
                    '    .Enabled = False
                    End With
                Next
                With CBar(i).Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=1)
                    .Caption = "Format BPCS Bill Of Material..."
                    .OnAction = "Format_BPCS_Excel"
                    .FaceId = 173
                    .Visible = True
                    .Enabled = True
                End With
                CBar(i).Visible = True
            End If
        Next
    End If

    'With CBar("Data").Controls.Item("Transfer &Data To iSeries...")
    '    .Enabled = False
    'End With

    'With CBar("Data").Controls.Item("T&ransfer Data From iSeries...")
    '    .Enabled = False
    'End With
    Set CBar = Nothing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this the code in the xlam?

Comment: What OS?  On Windows, if the file is marked as having been downloaded, you will see that behaviour.  Try the instructions at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/delay/p/unblockingdownloadedfile/ on the XLA file before installing it and see if that helps.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - It is still in .xla

Comment: @cxw - I tried that. I don't have that option.

Comment: Hmm... What version of Windows?

Comment: It is both Windows 7 & 10 there is an issue.

Comment: When using `.xlam` on the shared harddrive I solved this issue by: 1. Adding the trusted location to Excel (seems like you did it); 2. And, surprisingly, adding it in Internet Explorer (Settings-> Internet Options-> Security-> Local Intranet-> Sites-> Advanced-> Paste folder address and save). That had to be done on every machine.

Comment: @VictorK - Ok, but this is a .xla format.

Comment: @Valnurat I don't think that should make a difference, seeing how both are add-in formats.

Answer (score 1):

I work with add-ins and have struggled in the past with the same problem - add-in is selected in add-in list but it is not loaded when Excel opens. Approach below might not be able to solve your particular issue, but might prove to be helpful to others who encounter a similar problem. I have tried to muck about with a `Workbook_Open` code to load the add-ins but it wasn't solving the problem for me.

Symptoms: You have an Excel add-in (`.xlam`, `.xla`) on a shared drive. You add it to a list of add-ins in Excel. The first time you do it, it loads with no problem. Once you restart Excel, add-in does not load although it appears selected in add-in list.

Assumptions: You are using Windows, `.xlam`, `.xla` files are in a folder on a shared drive, that every user will be accessing.

Option 1 (has to be done on the user machine):

- Copy the folder path and paste it in the `Trusted Locations` in Excel. You will need to check the box that says `Allow trusted locations on my network`. (This is under File-> Options-> Trusted Center-> Trust Center Settings-> Trusted Locations)
- Next you have to also add this locations as a trusted location on the intranet. To do this you have to open `Internet Explorer`, go to Settings-> Internet Options-> Security-> Local Intranet-> Sites-> Advanced. There you should paste the folder path of your add-in, add and save. That part with `IE` was rather surprising to me and took me two days to find out after a lot of googling.
- Add your add-in to the list in Excel. When it promts you to copy the file into your personal folder select **NO**. Make sure that users of the add-in always select no, if all of them are supposed to use the same version of the add-in from the shared drive. If add-in is already selected it might be worth checking if Excel actually uses the intended copy and not the "personal folder" copy.

Option 2 (has to be done on the user machine):

- This is more of a workaround - you can give Excel a `Startup` folder. Under Options-> Advanced-> General you can add a folder path and Excel will open all of the files in that folder. You can just provide a folder with the add-in, but keep in mind Excel will open all Excel files in the specified folder and it might not be desirable for every user, so you might have to configure a separate `Startup` folder for every user and it might get cumbersome with a lot of users and more that one add-in, hence it is more of a workaround.

Again, this might not solve your problem, but it might be useful for others.

Comment: Thank you. Just for the record. The .xla file is located locally. I'm using one of the default trusted locations.